# Why is AutoField not working?

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

I created this field in my model:

```
numero_str = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default = 0)
```

The default value seems to invalidate the auto increment of AutoField but if I take it out I receive an error saying that the field can't be null. What I don't understand is: if I declareted it as a AutoField, isn't it supposed to generate a sequencial integer automatically? Or should I declare something when saving an item?

To be more especific, my app is basically a form that is send by e-mail and saved in a database. The error occur when sending (in case I take out the default value). It says:

```
IntegrityError at /solicitacaodetreinamento/

str_solicitacao.numero_str may not be NULL
```

Comment: Where do you receive this error about not being null? Post the exact message.

Comment: My guess is that the default is 0, perhaps you should use default=1 or add null=True

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert default=1 gives me the same error than default=0 and null=True returns "Primary key fields cannot have null=True"

Comment: What about if you delete default? Perhaps you should post the whole model.

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert deleting the default returns the "may not be NULL" error that I mentioned before. The rest of the model is ok, the problems only began when I included this particular field.

Comment: Try removing `unique=True` as well as its implicit for primary keys. Also, are you resetting db and doing sync again after the suggested changes?

Comment: @Rohan You're right unique is indeed implicid for primary key (I just removed it). I make a migration (I'm using South which disable SyncDB) but the error persists.

Comment: Your modal may have only one `primary_key=True` field.[Read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) for further information. Also, it can not be an `ALTER` to an existing model since django creates a primary key field automatically if there is no pre-defined one in model during the first model-database synchronization. Otherwise, it violates `Only one primary key is allowed on an object.` rule.

Comment: @FallenAngel Let me see if I understood: Django, by default, generated a primary key, then I tried to migrate a new primary key in substitution of the previous and that was the reason of my problem. Is that?

Comment: @RodrigoGuedes, On the first time you syncdb your model, django searches for `primary_key` attribute in the model fields. If it could not found any, then it creates one named `id`. If there is ona, then django do not create it.
Second, django will let you only have one field with attribute `primary_key`. in each model. This can be either defined by you in your model, or created automatically by django. [Read this and all realted topics](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key). I am no sure but it might be because of that.

Comment: @FallenAngel It's strange because South should delete the old primary key and the create the new one. But it can be the source of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: I deleted the DB file and all the migration of South (include the Initial). Then I recreated the database and made the migrations. This time, using the default primary key, i.e., "id". In my case it was simpler because I had no real data at all (it is not in production), otherwise I would have to export the data, recreate the database and then import the data. Thank you all.